# What is the value of $\ln(\ln(i))$?

Tags: complex-numbers, logarithms

I came across this question while practicing some quant interview questions. It simply asks the value of the above expression, no additional information is given.

I tried googling for it, Google tells me the result is -

$$\ln(\ln(i)) = 0.451582705 + 1.57079633i$$

I have no clue how to get this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Notice that $1.5707963... = \frac{\pi}{2} = e^{0.45158270...}$.

Comment: Probably Google used the "principal value" for the inner logarithm.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, $e^{\pi i/2}=i$, so $\log i$ is $\frac{\pi}{2}i$ -- plus or minus some multiple of $2\pi i$, but let us work with $\frac\pi2i$ as the principal value to begin with. Then
$$\log(\frac\pi2i) = \log(\frac\pi2) + \log i = \log(\frac\pi2) + \frac\pi2i $$

This matches Google's result, since $\log(\frac\pi2)\approx 0.452$ and $\frac\pi2\approx1.57$.

---

In is full multivalued glory, the possible values are
$$ \log\Bigl(\frac{4k_1+1+j}2\Bigr) + \log \pi + \frac{4k_2+1+j}2\pi i \qquad\qquad k_1 \in \mathbb N_0, k_2\in\mathbb Z, j\in\{0,2\}$$
(where the $j=2$ possibility is for the case that that we choose a $\log i$ on the *negative* imaginary axis for the first logarithm).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**
Given $z = r e^{i\theta}$, we have
$$\log z = \log r +i\theta,$$
and, of course,
$$\log r = \int_1^r \frac{1}{t} \mathrm{d}t.$$